# Excluding DOM element before storing text variable

Tags: jquery, selector, each

I am storing n entire DOM element in a variable, and I need to remove a sub element from the variable.

I am looping through all `tr` elements like so:

```
$("#directionsPanel tr").each(function(index){
      var excludeDistance = $(this).text();
});
```

But this is problematic. I want to remove a div from the `tr` before storing it's text in a variable. Below is the format of the tr that I am looping through:

```
<tr>
    <td>4.</td>
    <td>here is text</td>
    <td>
        <div class="adp-distance">0.7 mi</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to store the entire `tr` as a variable, EXCLUDING the `div` with a class of `.adp-distance`. The result I am looking for would be `4. here is text`

Thanks!

Comment: So.... remove the div before you call .text? i'm confused.

Comment: I do not want to remove it from the DOM, just the variable. And its an object, not a string

Comment: you don't have to work with the actual table row, clone it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
 var excludeDistance = $(this).clone().find('div.adp-distance').remove().end().text();
```